# Graph autoscale, python

Tags: python, graph, scale, axis

I've made a graph and here is my code:

```
def graphdraw(self):
        self.xaxis = []
        self.yaxis = []
        fig=plt.figure(1)
        self.ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
        plt.xlabel('Wavelenght[nm]')
        plt.ylabel('Intensity[arb. unit]')
        self.line, = self.ax.plot(self.xaxis,self.yaxis,'g-', linewidth=1.5, markersize=4)
        self.ax.set_xlim(-250,250)
        self.ax.set_ylim(0,40000)
    def drawg(self):
        self.graphdraw()
        i = -200
        while i <= 200:
            self.xaxis.append(i)
            self.yaxis.append(i*i)
            self.line.set_data(self.xaxis,self.yaxis)
            plt.draw()
            plt.pause(0.1)
            i = i + 1
```

But I'd like it to autoscale axis, and when i do something like this: `self.ax.autoscale_view(True,True,True)` instead of these lines: `self.ax.set_lim...` it does not work. I know it may be stupid and trivial question but can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, nevermind. I've made my own autoscale.

```
def graphdraw(self):
        self.xaxis = []
        self.yaxis = []
        fig=plt.figure(1)
        self.ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
        plt.xlabel('Wavelenght[nm]')
        plt.ylabel('Intensity[arb. unit]')
        self.line, = self.ax.plot(self.xaxis,self.yaxis,'g-', linewidth=1.5, markersize=4)
        self.ax.set_xlim(-250,250)
    def drawg(self):
        self.graphdraw()
        i = -200
        start = 50
        while i <= 200:
            z = random.randint(0,450)
            self.ax.set_ylim(0,start)
            self.xaxis.append(i)
            self.yaxis.append(z)
            if z > start:
                start= z
            self.ax.set_ylim(0,start + 50)
            self.line.set_data(self.xaxis,self.yaxis)
            plt.draw()
            plt.pause(0.1)
            i = i + 1
```